# Как переместить код двух классов в один

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

У меня есть два класса (1)MessageConfigurato 2)MessageInfoManager) сказали их удалить, но их код переместить в существующий MainView, можете помочь корректно переместить их код в Main View

MessageConfigurator

```
public class MessageConfigurator {

    private static MessageConfigurator messageConfigurator = null;
    private final MessagesInfoManager chatMessagesInfoManager = new MessagesInfoManager();

    private MessageConfigurator() {
    }

    public static MessageConfigurator getInstance() {
        if (messageConfigurator == null) {
            messageConfigurator = new MessageConfigurator();
        }
        return messageConfigurator;
    }

    public MessagesInfoManager getChatMessagesInfoManager() {
        return chatMessagesInfoManager;
    }
}
```

MessageInfoManager

```
public class MessagesInfoManager {


    private final List<MessageInfo> messagesInfoQueue = new ArrayList<>();

    private final Map<Optional<UI>, MessageList> messageListMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void updateMessageUIInfo(MessageInfo messageInfo) {

        addMessageInfo(messageInfo);
        Message message = messageInfo.getMessage();

        for (Map.Entry<Optional<UI>, MessageList> entry : this.messageListMap.entrySet()) {
            final Optional<UI> uiOptional = entry.getKey();
            final MessageList messageList = entry.getValue();
            uiOptional.ifPresent(ui ->

                    ui.access(() ->
                            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.getFrom() + ": " + message.getMessage()))
                    ));
        }
    }

    private void addMessageInfo(MessageInfo messageInfo) {
        if (!messagesInfoQueue.contains(messageInfo)) {
            this.messagesInfoQueue.add(messageInfo);
            this.messageListMap.putIfAbsent(messageInfo.getUI(), messageInfo.getMessageList());
        }
    }

    public List<Message> getMessagesByUI(Optional<UI> uiOptional) {
        return messagesInfoQueue
                .stream()
                .filter(messageInfo -> !messageInfo.getUI().equals(uiOptional))
                .map(MessageInfo::getMessage)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

MainView

```
@StyleSheet("frontend://styles/styles.css")
@Route
@PWA(name = "Vaadin MessagesInfoManager", shortName = "Vaadin MessagesInfoManager")
@Push
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final MessagesInfoManager messagesInfoManager;
    private final RestService restService;
    private String username;

    @Autowired
    public MainView(RestService restService) {
        this.messagesInfoManager = MessageConfigurator.getInstance().getChatMessagesInfoManager();
        addClassName("main-view");
        setSizeFull();
        setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);

        H1 header = new H1("Vaadin Chat");
        header.getElement().getThemeList().add("dark");

        add(header);

        askUsername();
        this.restService = restService;
    }

    private void askUsername() {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        TextField usernameField = new TextField();
        Button startButton = new Button("Start chat");

        layout.add(usernameField, startButton);

        startButton.addClickListener(click -> {
            username = usernameField.getValue();
            remove(layout);
            showChat(username);
        });

        add(layout);
    }

    private void showChat(String username) {
        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<Message> lasts = restService.getLast();
        for (Message message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.getFrom() + ": " + message.getMessage()));
        }

        add(messageList, createInputLayout(username, messageList));
        expand(messageList);
    }

    private Component createInputLayout(String username, MessageList messageList) {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        layout.setWidth("100%");

        TextField messageField = new TextField();
        messageField.addKeyDownListener(Key.ENTER, keyDownEvent -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
        sendButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

        layout.add(messageField, sendButton);
        layout.expand(messageField);

        messageField.addFocusListener(event -> {
            for (Message message : messagesInfoManager.getMessagesByUI(getUI())) {
                if (!message.getFrom().equals(username)) {
                    message.setUnread(false);
                    this.restService.updateMessage(message.getId(), message);
                }
            }
        });

        sendButton.addClickListener(click -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        messageField.focus();

        return layout;
    }

    private void sender(TextField textField, MessageList messageList) {
        Message message = new Message(username, textField.getValue());
        message = restService.saveMessage(message);
        messagesInfoManager.updateMessageUIInfo(new MessageInfo(messageList, message, this));
        textField.clear();
        textField.focus();
    }
```